# ActiveAdmin with IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, activeadmin

I have a client from which we have to develop a Rails app which requires the admin to work in IE8.

I usually develop websites with the git version of ActiveAdmin but I've noticed [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/unsupported_browser.rb) and [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml#L126) that IE8 is not supported.

My questions are:

- can I use it anyway?
- if so, how much do I lose?
- what's the last version of ActiveAdmin to support IE8?

Comment: @daniel it's not strictly an issue with ActiveAdmin per se, that's why I chose to open a question and not add to the 192 open issues in ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the guy that has written the noticed.

There is no strict point where active admin break with IE8. We only say, we don't support IE8, we don't give any guaranty that it will be work and we don't accept changes to fix IE8 problems.

You can use it, but you should test every JS/CSS related thing on IE8!

BTW: IE8 is no longer supported by Microsoft, so you customer should update his systems for security reasons. Would you dring 7 years old milk? ;)

Comment: Yeah I know MS has ceased support and I wholeheartedly agree, I'll try to argue that but I think the client's client still have XP. I'll investigate :-) Thank you for the response!